# Undefined method when uploading a file in Slim Framework

Tags: php, slim

When uploading a file I'm suddenly getting the following error:

```
Call to undefined method Slim\Http\UploadedFile::getMediaType()
```

The line of code in question is:

```
$uploaded_file['file']->getMediaType()
```

Strangely, nothing has changed in my code.  And the file does exist.  In fact, when I inspect `$uploaded_file['file']` I see it is an instance of Slim\Http\UploadedFile.

Here's the stack trace:

```
#0 [internal function]: Closure->{closure}(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response), Array)
#1 /var/www/app/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Handlers/Strategies/RequestResponse.php(41): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response), Array)
#2 /var/www/app/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Route.php(344): Slim\Handlers\Strategies\RequestResponse->__invoke(Object(Closure), Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response), Array)
#3 /var/www/app/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/MiddlewareAwareTrait.php(116): Slim\Route->__invoke(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response))
#4 /var/www/app/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Route.php(316): Slim\Route->callMiddlewareStack(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response))
#5 /var/www/app/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/App.php(438): Slim\Route->run(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response))
#6 /var/www/app/index.php(2759): Slim\App->__invoke(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response))
#7 [internal function]: Closure->{closure}(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response), Object(Slim\App))
#8 /var/www/app/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/DeferredCallable.php(43): call_user_func_array(Object(Closure), Array)
#9 [internal function]: Slim\DeferredCallable->__invoke(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response), Object(Slim\App))
#10 /var/www/app/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/MiddlewareAwareTrait.php(67): call_user_func(Object(Slim\DeferredCallable), Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response), Object(Slim\App))
#11 /var/www/app/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/MiddlewareAwareTrait.php(116): Slim\App->Slim\{closure}(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response))
#12 /var/www/app/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/App.php(332): Slim\App->callMiddlewareStack(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response))
#13 /var/www/app/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/App.php(293): Slim\App->process(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response))
#14 /var/www/app/index.php(2765): Slim\App->run()
#15 {main}
```

Comment: did you mean getClientMediaType()? https://github.com/slimphp/Slim-Http/blob/master/src/UploadedFile.php#L313

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after looking in [the source code](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim-Http/blob/master/src/UploadedFile.php#L313) it seems that the method you want to call is `getClientMediaType()` and not `getMediaType()`.

Try replacing your line with

```
$uploaded_file['file']->getClientMediaType()
```

Hope this helps

Comment: *sigh* Thank you.  Sometimes I'm amazed I'm able to put on foot in front of the other. ;)